# How can i access the user Role in Form Builder class in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the form as `UserType` with field like this

```
->add('description')
  ->add('createdAt')
```

Now i want that if the Logged in user has Role `(ROLE_SUPERADMIN)` then he can see extra fields like this

```
 ->add('description')
if($user.hasRole(ROLE_SUPERADMIN))
->add('createdAt')
```

Actually i have to do that for many fields . is there any way i can make some custom type so that if that type is there then only admin can see those like

`->add('createdAt',"MyCustomType")`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Pretty simple. Just make your custom form type a service, depending on the security context:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{

    private $securityContext;

    public function __construct(SecurityContext $securityContext)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        // Current logged user
        $user = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();

        // Add fields to the builder
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'required'   => false,
            'data_class' => 'Acme\HelloBundle\Entity\User'
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user_type';
    }
}
```

Then mark the class as a service, with the special tag `form.type`:

```
services:
    form.type.user:
        class: Acme\HelloBundle\Form\Type\UserType
        arguments: ["@security.context"]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: user_type }
```

In your controller, instead of doing `new UserType()`, grap the service from the container:

```php
$form = $this->createForm($this->get('form.type.user'), $data);
```

Comment: arguments: ["@security.authorization_checker"] after sf2.6
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221477/symfony2-check-user-role-in-service