# how to check the user role inside form builder in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, formbuilder, role

Okay, i'm trying to check if an user has a specific role, i did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11998761/how-can-i-access-the-user-role-in-form-builder-class-in-symfony2)

however, when i do this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('nombre',null,array('label' => 'Usuario'))
        ->add('email')
        ->add('password', 'repeated', array(
            'type' => 'password',
            'invalid_message' => 'Los campos deben coincidir',
            'first_name' => 'password',
            'second_name' => 'confirmar password',
            'options' => array('required' => false)
            ))

        ->add('cliente', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'ClientesBundle:Cliente',
        'empty_value' => 'Company',            
        'required'    => false,
        'empty_data'  => null)
    **)**
      $user = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
      **if ($user->getRol() == 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'){**
        ->add('rol') 
        **}**
    ;

}
```

tried this as well:

```
 **if ($this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser()->getRol() === 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'){**
            ->add('rol') 
            **}**
```

the bolded lines (the ones with **) have the tiny red line that indicates an error, and it's says unexpected if...
How do i fix this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From controller you have to pass user object to form builder

```
$form = $this->createForm(
    new YourType(), 
    $data, 
    array('user' => $this->getUser())
);
```

Then in form builder you can fetch it from `$options`:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $user = $options['user']
}
```

Don't forget to extend `setDefaultOptions()` with `user` index:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        ...
        'user' => null
    ));
}
```

Comment: That's what I have been looking for!

Comment: For SF3 Use: `public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)`
Instead of `setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)`

Answer (score 16):

If you declare your form type as a service, you can inject the token storage in your class.

So you declare the service in `services.yml` like this:

```
my_form:
    class: AppBundle\Services\MyFormType
    public: true
    arguments:  ['@security.token_storage']
```

And the form class like this:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;

class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
        // Use the user object to build the form
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the way to do it with Symfony! always use dependency injection.

Comment: In Symfony 3.4 I had to add tags: [form.type] in the services.yml

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old question, but I'd like to put forward a better alternative for checking roles inside a form type.

#### The issue

The issue with using the TokenInterface and the User object is that it does not check for inheritance. For example, consider the following `security.yml`:

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

If your user has `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` but not `ROLE_ADMIN` added to their roles, the above solutions will **fail** if you are using `$user->hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')`, as the user does not explicitly have `ROLE_ADMIN` assigned to their user and `hasRole()` does not check hierarchy.

---

#### The solution

Use the `AuthorizationCheckerInterface` instead to gain access to the `isGranted()` function.

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface;

class MyFormType extends AbstractType {

    protected $auth;

    public function __construct(AuthorizationCheckerInterface $auth) {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        
        // ...
        
        if($this->auth->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
            // Do the thing here
        }
    }
}
```

This will respect any hierarchy defined in `security.yml`. If we use the same yml file as above, `$auth->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')` will return *true* if a user has `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` but not `ROLE_ADMIN` assigned to their profile.

---

##### Update for Symfony 5 and above

The previous solution will still work in Symfony 5 and and above, however there are a few tweaks that can be made given Symfony 5's recommendations.

`Security` is now preferred over `AuthorizationCheckerInterface`, and if using PHP 8, you can use [Constructor Promotion](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.constructor.promotion)

```php
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class MyFormType extends AbstractType {

    public function __construct(protected Security $security) {
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
            
        // ...
            
        if($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
            // Do the thing here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I succeed in doing this thing without pass to a service in symfony 3.4. I know my method is not the most "professionnal" but it is simple and it works.

First, send the user in your formType from your controller

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(addPlanExpectedType::class, $business,
            array('user' => $this->getUser())
        );
```

Secondly, recover the roles, and verify if "ROLE_AMIN" is in this $roles array

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $businessId = $options['data']->getId();

        $user = $options['user'];
        $roles = $user->getRoles();

        $boolAdmin = in_array('ROLE_ADMIN', $roles);
```