# Symfony2 check user role in Service

Tags: symfony

How can I check user role in code of a symfony2 Service? Should I simply send a user roles object to a Service or is there solution which allows me to do the check from Service level?

Comment: What do you want to check? Do you want to check if user has a role? Or user has an access to some operation?

Comment: My service defines available tags to be added to certain entity's. Adding certain tags to entities requires user having given role. I want in service to check if given tag may be added by given user (taking into account roles that he has). Thus I need to have access to information on user role in my service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that:

- you inject `security.context` in your service

  ```
  public function __construct(SecurityContext $securityContext) {
    $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
  }
  ```
- you are using FosUserBundle
- I understood correctly your question :-)

you should be able to do:

```
$token = $this->securityContext->getToken();
if (empty($token)) {
    return [];
}
$user = $token->getUser();
if (empty($user)) {
    return [];
}
$roles = $user->getRoles();
```

### Updates 2016/11/28

1. Answer updated to pass the specific dependency instead of the whole container, as that is a bad practice (see comment by @Shady)
2. Note that starting from Symfony 2.6, **SecurityContext** is deprecated, you should use **TokenStorage** instead.

Comment: Thanks for the clue to pass the container to service. That was the thing that I needed.

Comment: Passing the container to a service is a bad practice.

Answer (score 13):

The other answers have you pass the container instead of the authorization checker. While they work they create a tight dependancy on the container making it harder to migrate your code to other projects. Instead you should only pass the authorization checker.

Here is an example taken from the [symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/securing_services.html).

app/config/services.yml

```
services:
    newsletter_manager:
        class:     "AppBundle\Newsletter\NewsletterManager"
        arguments: ["@security.authorization_checker"]
```

src/Appbundle/Newsletter/NewsletterManager.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Newsletter;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
// ...

class NewsletterManager
{
    protected $authorizationChecker;

    public function __construct(AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker)
    {
        $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
    }

    public function sendNewsletter()
    {
        if (false === $this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_NEWSLETTER_ADMIN')) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException();
        }

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Imho this should be accepted answer. Passing the container to a service is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

## EDIT @Mick - DO NOT EVER DO THE FOLLOWING

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221477/symfony2-check-user-role-in-service/47319975#47319975) for more info.

---

I think it would be much easier if you implemented an isGranted function in the User entity:

```
Class User implements UserInterface {
    ...
    public function isGranted($role)
    {
        return in_array($role, $this->getRoles());
    }
}
```

You can now easily check for granted roles in every layer of your application. In PHP:

```
$user->isGranted("USER_ADMIN")
```

Or in Twig:

```
user.granted("USER_ADMIN")
```

If you need to check a role for the current user, you can do this in Twig:

```
app.user.granted("USER_ADMIN")
```

Note: the variable "app" is globally defined.

Note 2: this code may throw an exception if you use it outside the secured area of your app, since app.user would be NULL.

Comment: I am using `FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle`. The question is how may I access information about roles in service?

Comment: In most cases, people will define a hierarchical role structure. The problem with this approach is that inherited roles are not taken into account. Better is to inject the ``security.authorization_checker`` service.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that to be able to use Symfony2 classes in service you need to provide service with a container.

Service definition:

```
services:
  /.../:
    class: /.../
    arguments: ['@service_container']
```

Service file:

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;

```
class globalHelper {    

    private $container;

    public function __construct(Container $container) {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
```

Comment: Injecting the whole service container is considered bad practice. [(source 1)](http://richardmiller.co.uk/2011/05/19/when-dependency-injection-goes-wrong/) [(source 2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931321/in-symfony2-why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-inject-the-service-container-rather-than-i) Unless you have a really good reason, inject the services that you need instead.

Answer (score 0):

## BE CAREFUL...

Be very careful about what you are doing when it comes to Security.. DO NOT DO [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221477/symfony2-check-user-role-in-service/47319975#31222156).

This is because, you need to understand that the [TokenInterface](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/TokenInterface.html) is not the same as [`UserInterface`](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserInterface.html).

> TokenInterface is the interface for the user authentication
>   information.

You must use it - If you don't have the token made available in your current service, use the [`SecurityContext`](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/SecurityContext.html) or the [`AccessDecisionManager`](http://api.symfony.com/3.2/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authorization/AccessDecisionManager.html).

---

***Note***: In Symfony > 2.6, some [improvements](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements) were made, and `SecurityContext` was deprecated, and split into [`TokenStorage`](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/Storage/TokenStorage.html) and [`AuthorizationChecker`](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authorization/AuthorizationChecker.html). So, you can go ahead and use `AuthorizationChecker` now.

---

Look! Even FOSUserBundle [implementation](https://github.com/phiamo/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/UserInterface.php#L170-L180) talks about it:

```
/**
 * Never use this to check if this user has access to anything!
 *
 * Use the SecurityContext, or an implementation of AccessDecisionManager
 * instead, e.g.
 *
 *         $securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_USER');
 *
 * @param string $role
 * @return Boolean
 */
function hasRole($role);
```

Look how it works, look at things like [getRoles](http://api.symfony.com/3.3/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/TokenInterface.html#method_getRoles), [Hierarchical roles](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#hierarchical-roles) for example.

ROLES in the database are not to be trusted - if you get a User object from the database, and use your `getRoles()` or even worse the special `isGranted($role)` you have created, they will NOT have the roles you expect your user to have.

[This](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security.html) should be your bible, and now you can understand the differences between:

<kbd>1</kbd> `$user->getRoles()`

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(10) "ROLE_ADMIN" 
    [1]=> string(9) "ROLE_USER" 
}
```

<kbd>2</kbd> `$this->token->getRoles()`

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> object(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role) 
        (1) { ["role":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role":private]=> string(10) "ROLE_ADMIN" } 
    [1]=> object(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role)
        (1) { ["role":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role":private]=> string(22) "ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH" } 
    [2]=> object(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role)
        (1) { ["role":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role":private]=> string(9) "ROLE_USER" } 

}
```

<kbd>3</kbd> `$this->token->getUser->getRoles()`

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(10) "ROLE_ADMIN" 
    [1]=> string(22) "ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH" 
    [2]=> string(9) "ROLE_USER" 
}
```

When you have <kbd>security.yml</kbd>

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```